# App does not launch in full screen when running on iOS 7.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I use XCode 6.2 and created a new blank single page application. I changed the target to 7.0 and run it in a `iPhone5 7.1`simulator. The result is the following:

[image]

I did not change anything. When I launch on a 8.0 simulator the app launches in full screen.

**How can I achieve that the app takes the entires screen?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use LaunchImage. You can set it from project settings->General tab.

Comment: Well this is not the launch image it is the app screen after the launch image.

Comment: Yes, i know. it is strange but when you use a LaunchImage (any image, not a specific one) the app spreads all over the screen. At least it works for me every time.

Comment: Could you please explain how to do this? Does this mean I cannot use the ``LaunchScreen.xib``?

Comment: I don't have my Mac here, sorry. No, LaunchScreen.xib is used when it runs on iOS8, but as you know we could use only a static image before iOS8. In fact, you don't need to specify a image, go to project setting (General-Info-Build Settings... tabs), go to General tab, there is a LaunchImage section, click something like Use LaunchImage and pick the default one. Then it should work.